# How to set some values within each column to zero based on the number of their repetition?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of 117,000 rows with 10,000 columns containing values, some being repeated frequently and some not. I aim to replace those values being repeated less than 100 times within each column to zero. I put a small example here:
my input is like this:

```
1 200 444
2 310 000
3 310 000
4 444 444
5 200 444
6 200 112
7 310 444
8 310 876
9 310 876
10 444 876
```

I need in  my output  any value which is repeated less than 3 times within a column be set to zero (for example in column 1, value 444 is repeated less than 3 times, so it should be set as zero and the same should be done for values 000 and 112 in column 2) :

```
1 200 444
2 310  0
3 310  0
4  0  444
5 200 444
6 200  0
7 310 444
8 310 876
9 310 876
10 0  876
```

Could any body help me by writing a script to do this in R for a huge data.frame? (117000 rows and 10000 column)?

Comment: Are these "numbers" numbers or character? The number `0` would not normally display as `000`.

Comment: @jlhoward: that is right. you can consider them as characters.

Comment: If that's the case, you cannot mix numeric and character in a single column. You could set to `NA` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to incorporate @Arun's comments, and to demo with a dataset more representative of the real case.

This question is really interesting primarily because the full dataset is so large (117,000 rows X 10,000 columns). So the main issue is not how to flag the less common entries, but how to do that efficiently. This shows three options: a data.frame option, a naive data.table option (mine), and a sophisticated data.table option (@Arun's). It's an object lesson in the superiority of data.table, especially when used correctly.

```
# create sample: 117,000 rows, 100 columns (1% of real case)
set.seed(1)    # for reproducibility
ltrs <- sapply(letters,function(x)paste(rep(x,3),collapse=""))
df   <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(ltrs, 117e3, replace = TRUE, 
                                        p=c(0.5,0.3,0.1,0.09,rep(0.01/22,22)))), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

So this data-set has 117,000 rows and 100 columns (100% of the rows, 1% of the columns). Each entry is a three letter string ("AAA", "BBB", etc). AAA - DDD account for 99% of the entries and the other 22 letters collectively account for the remaining 1%. So there are bound to be instances of these with frequency < 100.

```
# data.frame option
set.col <- function(x) {
  tbl <- table(x)
  x[x%in%names(tbl)[tbl<100]]<-NA
  x
}
system.time(
  result.1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df,set.col))
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#   44.52    0.27   44.95
```

So the data.frame option runs in ~44 sec (on my system). The real case would run in ~4400 sec, or about 73min.

```
# naive data.table
library(data.table)
result.2 <- as.data.table(df)
system.time(
  for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
    tbl <- table(result.2[[j]])
    set(result.2, i=which(result.2[[j]]%in%names(tbl)[tbl<100]),j=j, NA)
  }
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.51    0.05    1.56
```

The naive data.table approach still uses `table(...)` but takes advantage of `set(...)`. It runs about 30X faster. The full data-set would run in about 3 min.

```
# sophisticated data.table
# install.packages("data.table", type="source")   # requires 1.9.6+
library(data.table)
result.3 <- as.data.table(df)
system.time(
  for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
    tbl <- result.3[,.N,by=c(names(result.3)[j])][N<100]
    result.3[tbl, c(names(result.3)[j]):=NA, on=c(names(result.3)[j])]
  }
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.65    0.00    0.67 
identical(result.2,result.3)
# [1] TRUE
```

The sophisticated data.table solution runs 2.5X faster still, and about 70X faster than the data frame option. The full data-set should run in about 65 sec.

The following just demonstrates that option 3 works with the example in the question:

```
# import sample data
df <- read.table(header=F, row.names=1, colClasses=c("character"),
                 text="1 200 444
                 2 310 000
                 3 310 000
                 4 444 444
                 5 200 444
                 6 200 112
                 7 310 444
                 8 310 876
                 9 310 876
                 10 444 876")
result.3 <- as.data.table(df)
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
  tbl <- result.3[,.N,by=c(names(result.3)[j])][N<3]
  result.3[tbl, c(names(result.3)[j]):=NA, on=c(names(result.3)[j])]
}

result.3
#      V2  V3
#  1: 200 444
#  2: 310  NA
#  3: 310  NA
#  4:  NA 444
#  5: 200 444
#  6: 200  NA
#  7: 310 444
#  8: 310 876
#  9: 310 876
# 10:  NA 876
```

To write the result to a csv file, use something like:

```
write.csv(result.3, file="myfile.csv")
```

Comment: @ jIhoward: why did you name it as df? and how could you extract this output from R ?

Comment: [1] There's nothing special about the name. You didn't specify. [2] Not sure what you mean by "extract this output from R", but to save the result to a csv file, use, e.g.,  `write.csv(df,file="mydf.csv")`. [3] Also, I assumed the first column was an actual column, and not row names.

Comment: @ jlhoward: the first column was row names. should I change something in script please?

Comment: I reworked the answer based on your input in the comments, and mindful that your actual dataset is extremely large ( > 1GB in size). I also included the code used to import your example, just so we have a common understanding of `df`.

Comment: One I could think of is to replace `table()` with `dt[, .N, by=names(dt)[j][N < 3L]` and then do a join in the next step. Runs in about 80s on my machine. Second way is (if the column values are all > 0L, and are integers) is to replace `table()` with `tabulate()`.

Comment: @Arun I tried that but, for me, `dt[, .N, by=names(dt)[j]][N < 3L]` throws the error: `Error in ... : 'by' appears to evaluate to column names but isn't c() or key()...`. If I use the suggested alternative, `dt[, .N, by=eval(names(dt)[j])][N < 3L]` the code runs 20X slower than `table(dt[j])`. I'm using data.table 1.9.6. If this isn't supposed to happen I'll post as a separate question with MRE.

Comment: @ jlhoward: thank you very much. i wish your script work for my huge data as well.

Comment: @Arun Implemented your suggestion, with benchmarks.

Comment: @jlhoward thanks. Not sure how to avoid the `[.data.table` overhead yet though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a solution for a similar problem to the one you laid out in your simplified version. The comments should explain it as it goes along.

Here we replace all elements which appear strictly less than four times, so the whole second column of the `test_df` should go to zero.

```
# Creates fake test dataframe 
col1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
col2 <- c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
test_df <- data.frame(col1, col2)

# Finds the number of occurences of every element in the dataframe
occurences <- table(unlist(test_df))

# Find the unique elements across the whole dataframe 
elements <- unique(unlist(test_df))

# Creates an empty vector for all elements less than four 
elements_less_than_four <- c()

# Loops through all elements in the dataframe and if they appear less than
# four times puts them in a list 
for(el in elements){

  if( occurences[[el]] < 4){ 
    elements_less_than_four <- c(elements_less_than_four, el) 
  }

}

# Unlist the df for quick comparison, turn all necessary values to zero.
unlisted_df <- as.vector(unlist(test_df))
correct_values <- replace(unlisted_df, unlisted_df %in% elements_less_than_four, 0)

# Reformats the dataframe
finished_df <- data.frame(matrix(correct_values, nrow = nrow(test_df), 
                          ncol = ncol(test_df), byrow = FALSE))
```

Comment: I ran your script and in the result I saw for second column vale 3 did not set as zero while it repeated only once within column2. could you please edit your script in the way it 3 get zero within column2?

Comment: @JCoolerton:I ran your script and in the result I saw for second column vaule 3 did not set as zero while it was repeated only once within column2. could you please edit your script in the way it 3 get zero within column2?

Comment: Oh, actually it's right that 3 didn't go to zero, as it's repeated more than four times across the whole data frame. So that code should do what it's supposed to :).